# when i use Fetch_array(); i get an error

Tags: php, mysqli

When I do the following query:

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT host,challenger FROM escrow WHERE id='$mid'");
$row = $sql->mysqli_fetch_array();
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::mysqli_fetch_array() in /home/lexhome09/public_html/challenges/report_match_form/index.php on line 8

What am I missing here?

Comment: As already stated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php), when using the object oriented interface:

its just simply `->fetch_array()`:

When using the procedural interface, then use the prefix `mysqli_`

`mysqli_fetch_array(result set, type)`

Better yet use prepared statements as well since you're using the improved version.

Comment: **Note:** `host` is a [MySQL Reserved Word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) - meaning you'll have to wrap it in back-ticks - `\`host\``. Also, as stated, it's `$sql->fetch_array()` as you're using the OO way. If it was procedural, you'll use `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Comment: @Darren It's a "keyword", not a "reserved" word. Notice there's no `(R)` next to it ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's too early for me lol :-( I guess I derp hard haha

Comment: @Darren double espresso for you ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- You've got a deal!

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$row = $sql->mysqli_fetch_array();
```

to:

```
$row = $sql->fetch_array();
```